# "To have it [be] <something>" construction?

Tags: construction

I have several times come across this construction in which the verb *have* is followed by the verb *be*, although normally *be* is omitted as saying just *have* is enough to convey the meaning. Are the following valid sentences?

- Can I make a new account and have it be approved?
- The whole point of HART is to have it be independent of politics.
- Have it be easy.
- We just couldn't have it be like it was last time, which was almost complete domination by them.

Is the "be" necessary in these sentences, or even correct? Could you please explain?

Comment: The _be_ is the result of a _to_-less infinitive (because this construction allows it -- _Have him stand up/tell us/change clothes_), and, since the _to_ is already missing, _to be_-Deletion just has the _be_ left to delete. That's what's happened here. So, the _be_ is correct, but it is optional, just as _to be_ is optional in _He wanted us (to be) ready by 5._

Comment: If they were written the way you would normally write without "be",  these sentences would make sense. However, "Have it easy" , even without "be" isn't clear. Could you please explain what is meant here?

"be" has no grammatical function in these sentences.

Comment: Suggest use 'Make it easy', instead of 'Have it be easy'.

Comment: I guess English has evolved to the point that these sentences look awful despite being grammatically correct!

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the "be" is necessary, when its subject is an agent.  Suppose you're letting your daughter stay with your parents for the summer, and you're telling your parents about the dating policy you'd like them to follow for her.  You say "Have her be home by 10pm."  That means that your parents should require your daughter, when she goes on a date, to make sure she is back at your parents house by 10pm.  But "Have her home by 10pm" would mean something quite different.  That would mean your parents were somehow in direct control of her movements, and she no longer counts as an agent.

Comment: That's a very good example.